# grpc-go: input payload not getting compressed

Tags: go, compression, grpc, grpc-go

I am trying to communicate with two services of mine via gRPC using compression.

I am trying to compress message at client side with the gzip compressor by adding the following `DialOption` when getting connection:
`grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions( grpc.UseCompressor(gzip.Name), )` at the client side.

At the server side I am just importing the gzip path to register the compressor. When adding the compressor option I am getting error:

`rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: received message after decompression larger than max (11355560 vs. 4194304)`

Although I understand that this might be due to the incoming message size limit at server side which is 4Mb, I am unable to understand why I get the following error when sending the same payload but without adding the `UseCompressor DialOption` :

`rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: received message larger than max (11355560 vs. 4194304)`

I am confused that why it is showing the message size for both cases when using compression or not. The first error message shows that decompression is done but it is not compressing the data as it is not increased in other request.

Answer (score 0):

The message size is checked after decompression. This is why the same size is reported. It does not report the compressed message size.

And this is why you get **similar** error messages when sending compressed or uncompressed messages.

Notice the difference:

- received message **after decompression** larger than max
- received message larger than max